# Should we require a user to press on EDIT button before allowing him to move/ delete from list of items (collection view)

Tags: android, ios, edit

Currently, in one of my Android apps, I provide an very obvious way, for user to delete/ move from list of items.

[image]

1. "X" button to delete
2. "=" button to move

---

Now, I'm porting such page to iOS app.

When I look at iOS common app, they usually do not provide such obvious way to move/ delete from list of items

---

### Read only

[image]

In order to move/ delete from list of items, user need to perform 1 extra step: **Tapping on top right EDIT button.**

---

### Edit mode after tapping on top right EDIT button

[image]

---

I am more lean toward bring the more "obvious" design to iOS platform. Reason is that

1. User needs not to perform an extra step (Tap on EDIT button) in order to delete/ move the items
2. It is not easy to accidentally press "X" or "=" button, as they occupy small space
3. Such design is proven in Android ecosystem. A large number of users (More than millions) just love this design.

---

Do you think, should I adopt this design in iOS? Or, I still should provide an **EDIT** button?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding the delete and move buttons directly in the list. It's your own design choice. A reason why many apps choose not to show delete and move buttons all the time is because they add clutter and aren't needed all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to **follow each platform's conventions**, that way the iOS user will know how it works, and same for your Android users.

Unless:
Also want to mention that if you are using a pre-existing framework such as Google's **Material Design**, then follow Material Design guidelines suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question.

Generally, following the principle that it doesn't matter how many click the user do if all of these clicks bring him closest to his goal, doing one more click in order to edit item, it's superfluous.

So the question is purely "aesthetic": you are right that such design is proven in Android ecosystem, but also the other design is proven and also appreciated by a large community of users.

So what is your target? Personally I will take some time to identify the "Personas" that will use your application, as well as the market you are going to navigate; i think that, in this scenario, the correct UX will be played here.

Answer (score 0):

No, I would recommend that you follow the standard design patterns of the native platform.

The reason for this is users are more familiar with the platform they use regularly. Their regular usage of each platform has familiarized them with its native design patterns. Rarely would users be familiar with more than 1 platform (unless they are designers or developers)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should follow what is there in iOS. I partially disagree with GCiandro.

Not providing EDIT button, in this case, introduce a basic flaw in design that deletion and movement can disrupt user's view accidentally and cause loss of data.

Providing Edit button ensures that User is playing deliberately which lifts responsibility from app design.

We should provide ways to curb data loss and abruption which User can face accidentally as much as possible.